# How to reset Entity Framework Migrations back to square one?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an asp.net core web api with a connection to a postgres db. I added a migration via dotnet ef cli and updated my database via:

```
dotnet ef migrations add initial
dotnet ef database update
```

There was no problem and I found my newly generated tables and the migration history in my schema. Then I messed up and did the same from a different project with a different name but with the same connection string. I used the same commands as above.

Now I cannot access neither the migration history table nor the generated tables anymore:

```
ERROR: must be owner of relation __EFMigrationsHistory
```

I wasn't able to get the rights for my migration history again.
How do I reset this to square one? Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try to drop your database and then use `dotnet ef database update initial` ?

Comment: It might help: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate

Comment: The same thing happened when I started from scratch. There might be something wrong with my role assignment in the database configuration. Thanks though